# SixLabors.ImageSharp Compressing image is making the image bigger as a byte

Tags: asp.net-core, image-processing, image-compression, imagesharp

I have compress method which is uses SixLabors.ImageSharp. When i compress a image on that method, its getting more size before then i upload it. The image i upload is 2,03 mb [image]

and when its come out from the compression method, its getting like that 4,54 mb [image]

and here it's my compression method :

```
public async Task<FileRepo> FileUploadToDatabase(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        using var image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream());
        IImageEncoder imageEncoderForJpeg = new JpegEncoder()
        {
            Quality = 80,
        };
        IImageEncoder imageEncoderForPng = new PngEncoder()
        {
            CompressionLevel = PngCompressionLevel.Level9,
        };
        _fileRepo = new FileRepo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            FileExtension = fileExtension,
            FileType = file.ContentType,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (fileExtension == ".png")
            {
                image.Save(ms, imageEncoderForPng);
            }
            if (fileExtension == ".JPEG" || fileExtension == ".jpg")
            {
                image.Save(ms, imageEncoderForJpeg);
            }
            await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
            _fileRepo.FileData = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return _fileRepo;
}
```

i dont know whats wrong with that method , it should be less size then first one right ?
let me know if that question is duplicate.

Comment: So much unnecessary code here. `Load` can tell you the `IImageFormat` (*You should never trust file extensions*). You're probably saving 24bit pngs as 32bit also.

Comment: is this a common thought ? because i wanna believe you. its not working in a way exactly what i wanted.  i have look around to find some examples but i couldnt find. its seems like i wont  compress them for now @JamesSouth . and as u said,sometimes its returnig .jpeg files  as .png.

Comment: Png will always be bigger than Jpeg when encoding photographic style images. Jpeg is specifically designed to store the data in a manner that works well with the human eye. Png does much better when working with areas of flat color.

https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_Load_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Configuration_System_IO_Stream_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Formats_IImageFormat__

Comment: @JamesSouth this is the first time im doing that process. im doing that compression for product photos which is gonna display on the e-commerce website.  my page is downloading 25 mb (40 product Photos,10 category photos) data because of those pics and its making the site slower. i wanna reduce that as long as i can. which way is much better for your experience ?

Comment: If it's ASP.NET Core Use ImageSharp.Web middleware to produce thumbnails. https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp.web Only show full size images when required.